# Skype4Java no swt-win32-3325

Tags: java, skype4java

I downloaded Skyp4Java from [Skype.sourceforge.jp](http://skype.sourceforge.jp/index.php?Skype%20API%20For%20Java%20%28English%29), I imported all the recommended jars

```
skype.jar
swt.jar
swt-win32-3139.dll <-- can't find that one
```

But I can't find the 'swt-win32-3139.dll' in the download anywhere. When I try to run the program I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3325 or swt-win32 in swt.library.path, java.libary.path or the jar file
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.TCHAR.<clinit>(TCHAR.java:29)
    at com.skype.connector.windows.WindowsConnector.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.skype.connector.Connector.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.skype.Utils.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.skype.Skype.getVersion(Unknown Source)
    at terminal.Terminal.doCommand(Terminal.java:208)
    at terminal.Terminal.inputActionPerformed(Terminal.java:143)
    at terminal.Terminal.access$000(Terminal.java:25)
    at terminal.Terminal$1.actionPerformed(Terminal.java:45)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:508)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:721)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:836)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1664)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2879)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2926)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the DLL here [SWT 3.1.1](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.1.1-200509290840/swt-3.1.1-win32-win32-x86.zip)  Note that it's the 32 bit binaries so if you need it for another platform, you'll need to get it from [SWT Project Page](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)